# use file from host as input for lineinfile module

Tags: ansible

I'm currently setting up a system with ansible and want to automate it as much as possible.

So I'm creating the public keys on my ansible machine and copy them to the hosts so that I can control the hosts as much as possible from the outside.

Now I need to setup connectivity between my hosts via public keys.
I'm using the `lineinfile` module to ensure that the keys are present in the `authorized_keys` and `known_hosts`files. Is there a way to read the contents of a file (on the machine from where ansible is run) and use it as input for the `lineinfile` module?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003880/ansible-set-variable-to-file-content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mxx pointed out in the comments, `lookup` is the answer.  Furthermore, I would not recommend using the `lineinfile` for adding authorized_keys.  There is already an Ansible module specifically for that, and it's a lot less likely to get you into trouble.  Here's an example play.  It will grab from the local public key, and properly make sure it exists for the target user.

`tasks:
 - name: Install SSH authorized key
   authorized_key: >
    user=root 
    key="{{ lookup('file', '/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}" 
    state=present`